# What is diff" between ./ and ../ path in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, jsx

Folder struchar.

```
react-app\
  src\
    tut\
      s.js
  data.js
```

What shout I write in s.js for import the data.js?

Comment: Its not just react. `./` is the current path. `../` is the path one level up.

Comment: Thanks, if i wirte =>import React from 'react';  <= it mens path is point to node_modules?

Comment: Yes, when you import from `node_modules` you don't need to specify the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./ means the current directory

../ means the parent of the current directory, not the root directory

/ is the root directory

example.text is in the current directory, as is ./example.text

../example.text is one level above you and /example.text lives in your root directory